# How to get a Supplier from an instance?

Tags: java, java-stream

I use the stream API from java8 and got the problem when I map an object to another object and pass this object to a method which expects a supplier, I get a compile error. How do I pass this object to the method?

For a better explanation, I wrote following code:

```
public class SimpleTest {
    public static class B{
       public static B mapFrom(A a){
          return new B(); //transform to b
       }
    }

    public static class A{
    }

    public static Integer mapToSomethingElseWith(Supplier<B> b){
       return 1;
    }


   public static void example(){
      List<A> a = Lists.newArrayList(new A(),new A(),new A());
      List<Integer> l = a.stream()
         .map(B::mapFrom)
         .map(SimpleTest::mapSomethingElseWith); //does not work. Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.lang.Integer to R
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

My current (ugly) solution looks like this:

```
List<Integer> l = a.stream()
     .map(B::mapFrom)
     .map((b)-> ((Supplier) () -> b)      // map to supplier
     .map(SimpleTest::mapSomethingElseWith)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Exists something similar but more expressive?

Comment: Doesn't `.map(b -> () -> b)` work?

Comment: No i have tried this and following error occured:
target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface

Comment: you invoke `mapToSomethingElseWith()` but it is declared `mapToSomethingElseWith()`

Comment: sry was an typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write :

```
 List<Integer> l = a.stream()
         .map(B::mapFrom)
```

You get a `Stream<B>` as the `mapFrom()` method returns `B` :

```
 public static B mapFrom(A a){...}
```

Then, you chain the `Stream<B>` with :

```
.map(SimpleTest::mapSomethingElseWith);
```

`mapToSomethingElseWith()` is defined as `mapToSomethingElseWith(Supplier<B> b)`.

So, the compiler expects to have a `mapToSomethingElseWith()` method with as argument  `Supplier<B>` and not `B` but you pass a `B` variable to.

A way of solve your problem is using the `map()` method with an explicit lambda that invokes `mapToSomethingElseWith()` with a `Supplier<B>`.

`()-> b` where `b` is the argument of type `B` of the lambda is a `Supplier<B>`.
It takes indeed no arg and it returns a `B` instance.

You can so write :

```
map(SimpleTest::mapSomethingElseWith);
  List<Integer> l = a.stream()
     .map(B::mapFrom)          
     .map(b->SimpleTest.mapToSomethingElseWith(()-> b) )
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

How about combining the last two `map`s:

```
List<Integer> l = a.stream()
     .map(B::mapFrom)
     .map(b -> SimpleTest.mapSomethingElse (() -> b))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why not combine *all* `map`s, `map(a -> SimpleTest.mapSomethingElse(() -> B.from(a)))`…