# Java: Creating a Supplier for a new instance of an Object from an instantiated Object

Tags: java, lambda, java-17, functional-interface

I want to create a Java `Supplier` from an existing instantiated Java object. Something like this would do:

```
CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
Supplier<CustomObject> newInstanceSupplier = Supplier.of(customObject)
```

This syntax for `Supplier` however does not exist for Java and I am wondering whether there is a convenient solution to this one.

I know I could easily create a supplier like this:

```
Supplier<CustomObject> supplier = ()-> new CustomObject()
```

or

```
Supplier<CustomObject> supplier = CustomObject::new
```

However, in my use-case, I want to take the `Supplier` from an existing custom object to allow for abstraction.

Is there a convenient way to do so?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142151/how-to-get-a-supplier-from-an-instance) tackles a slightly different approach.

Comment: not a 'good' approach, but if you make your `CustomObject implements Supplier<CustomObject>`, in the `get` method `return this` .. then  `CustomObject object = new CustomObject(); Supplier<CustomObject> supplier = object;`

Comment: I also found this solution:
`() -> customObject.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: Err, `Supplier<CustomObject> supplier = existingObject::get;`? or whatever the method name in `existingObject` is. Or perhaps `Supplier<CustomObject> supplier = () -> existingObject`? It's hard to know exactly what you mean here.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want a new instance? with same data/field content? Or do you just want the `Supplier` to return the already existing (same) instance (that is `() -> customObject`)?

Comment: Your question does not make sense, please edit it as you've contradicted yourself by saying "I want to create a Java Supplier from an existing instantiated Java object. " and then "I also found this solution: () -> customObject.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()" which is creating a new instance.

Comment: @DuncG I believe they did not mean "I want to create a Supplier that returns the given instance" but "a Supplier that returns a new instance from an existing instance", that is not "Supplier from existing instance" but "given an instance, create a Supplier"  (but just my opinion - based on the 3 code snippets posted by OP) ((not all people are native English speakers/writers/...))

Comment: @user16320675 They certainly aren't. The three code snippets are followed by the words '***however*** [my emphasis], in my use-case, I want to take the `Supplier` from an existing custom object.' In other words the snippets don't do what he wants. I don't see how this could possibly be more clear.

Comment: @user207421 (i) the third is "I also found this solution:" and not "however"; (ii) they *apparently* meant that the two first snippets only create an instance of a FIXED class, a class given at compile time;  they (*apparently*) want the new instance to be from the same class as the given instance (like from a template)

Answer (score 4):

Suppliers are not created that way. There is no static method `Supplier#of(...)` in the standard JDK.

If you want to create a `Supplier` supplying a previously created instance, do this:

```java
CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
Supplier<CustomObject> supplier = () -> customObject;
```

Though doing this, you lose the benefits of lazy instantiation as the instance becomes always instantiated before and regardless of whether the `supplier` is called or not.

Finally, remember the instance `customObject` must be marked as `final` or stay "effectively final", i.e. you can't reassign to it anything else.

Comment: from the question. OP apparently: (i) knows that there is no `Supplier#of()` - "*This syntax for Suppliers however does not exist for Java*"; (ii) needs a `Supplier` for a type not known at compile time; (iii) wants a `new` instance of the same class, not just that instance.

Comment: @user16320675 I don't see anything in the question about wanting a new instance. On the contrary, he states the object is already existing and instantiated.

Comment: "`()-> new CustomObject()`", "`CustomObject::new`" and even in OPs comment on the question "`... .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`"

Comment: @user16320675 To be honest, the comment came long after my answer. At the time of asking, the question seemed complete to me so I answered it and didn't track comments any longer.

Comment: @user16320675 Nope, as far as I check the question history, there is nothing that resembles my snippet.

Comment: @user16320675 None of these is even close to `Supplier<CustomObject> supplier = () -> customObject;` that is in my answer. I just edited the formatting, not the code itself. #facts

Comment: I don't really get your point. Feel free to downvote and move on.

Comment: @user16320675 That was me that said that, not Nikolas, and I stand by it. The OP specifically states that he 'want[s] to take the Supplier from an existing custom object'.

Comment: @user16320675 You are contradicting the OP's own words.